# React-scripts build failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/Stick-z/mern-shopping
Whenever I try to deploy to heroku, I get this error: `Exit status 254`  I think it is because of the react-scripts-build, because I have seen it before when deploying it somewhere else.

Comment: This may be of some use to your situation => https://github.com/bradtraversy/mern_shopping_list/issues/7 .

Answer (score 0):

Try

"build": "react-scripts build"

In package.json.